# Creating Sine wave Signal in Flutter (FFT)

Tags: flutter, dart, signals, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to create a mock signal to input into my Fast Fourier transform so to test if it is working, though, after countless hours of struggle, I realize that the issue is the signal I generate using the standard formula for a sinewave y=a*sin⁡(bx) in my code I have to generate the signal although it seems like from the signal data that the signal is showing a sin but the frequency is way off and is undetectable from my FFT.

```
List<double> generateMockSignal() {
 // Generate a sine wave with the given output specifics.
 final double amplitude = 50.0; // Amplitude of the wave
 final double frequency = 0.01; // Frequency of the wave
 final double phase = 0.0; // Phase shift of the wave
 final int numSamples = 100; // Number of samples to generate
 final List<double> signal = List.generate(numSamples, (i) {
   return amplitude * sin(2 * pi * frequency * i + phase);
 });

 return signal;

List<Complex> performFFT(List<double> signal) {
  final fft = FFT(signal.length);
  final freq = fft.realFft(signal);
  final complexFreq = freq.map((f) => Complex(f.x, 0)).toList();

  return complexFreq;
```

What I have tried is to generate a signal straight from raw data to feed it into my FFT and again my data is way off I am getting reading but they are not correct in the slightest and look like random numbers on each of the freq bins, it's like Flutter has no idea what a signal is and when I try to give it information about what a signal is it translates it to something way different. When I crank the amplitude up to some extremely unrealistic number I do get the bleed effect from my FFT window showing random noise values in all of the frequency bins. but when I try to input the signal by doing it the right way and creating the formula for a sine wave im getting zero reading on all my freq bins

```
yes, I have imported all the lib I need!
```

Comment: Your formula `sin(2*pi*f*t)` and using `i` for `t` implies that your sampling rate is 1 Hz (1 sample per second) - is that your intention? If not, you have units problem. If yes, did you mean to create a single period (100 samples) of 0.01 Hz signal? You also need to make sure the units are correct on your FFT bins axis

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the frequency i had mistakenly set it as 0.01 as i have tested various freqencies to see if there were any detection by the fft i ussualy have it at 1 herz. Tbh i want to test it with a freq of 1 hertz with a sampling rate that satesfies the nyquist therom which i know would be 2 but im guesing setting the sampling rate to 50 wouldnt be so much of an issue, also i want the amplitude to be 1 or above to be easily detectable by my FFT. would the signal be correct if i changed it
    numSamples, (i) => sin( signalAmplitude * pi * frequency * i / sampleRate),

Comment: Agian thank you so much for your answer being able to more specifically locate the problem being a units problem has given me alot more hope, can you elaborate what you mean with  "You also need to make sure the units are correct on your FFT bins axis"
agian i deeply aprichate the help

Comment: the center freq of bin `k` is `k*Fs/N`  where `Fs` is the sampling frequency and `N` the number of samples used to calculate the FFT. I suggest you look for some introductory web page for FFT, there are a lot out there